# Why some rust types provide static methods instead of object methods?

Tags: rust

Looking at the [Rc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) interface I found that the `Rc` struct has methods but they are defined without `self` so they are static but nothing actually prevents them to be usual object methods. The question is why they are defined so? Why, for example, the [Rc::weak_count](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.weak_count) is defined in the form:

```
fn weak_count(this: &Rc<T>) -> usize
```

instead of:

```
fn weak_count(&self) -> usize
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is to prevent shadowing methods that would otherwise be visible through the `Deref` and `DerefMut` implementations of `Rc`.  To quote the [documentation of `Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html):

> The inherent methods of `Rc` are all associated functions, which means that you have to call them as e.g. `Rc::get_mut(&mut value)` instead of `value.get_mut()`. This avoids conflicts with methods of the inner type `T`.

For example, if you have `Rc<Foo>` where `Foo` defines its own method called `weak_count`, using a static method would allow the user to write `foo.weak_count(…)` to call `Foo::weak_count` and `Rc::weak_count(&foo)` to call `Rc::weak_count`.

(For this reason, adding an intrinsic method to a type that defines `Deref` / `DerefMut` will break backward compatibiltiy).

Comment: I have missed the official docs on the same page... I must be very bad. I'd downvote myself :)